# What are the laws about selling random things on ebay for EU-based private person?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, european-union, europe, ebay

I was thinking to sell some things I don't use anymore on eBay and I was wondering if I should register or tax it somehow? I'm a private EU citizen and that's where I reside, and I assume that I would mostly sell things to EU citizens too as shipping otherwise would just be too costly. I don't have planned any profits of course because I don't even know if my stuff could be sold, and if it could, how much people are willing to pay for it, so please include that in your answer if it matters. :-)

Comment: [You don’t pay Income Tax on money you get from occasionally selling personal possessions online (but you may need to pay Capital Gains Tax).](https://www.gov.uk/income-from-selling-services-online). Other countries might differ but I suspect this rule is pretty common across the EU.

Comment: Can't speak for all of the EU. In Germany you do not pay taxes if you are a private seller, however the boundaries between being a private seller and running a business is not very clearly defined and is set by the tax office on a case by case basis, depending on the number of sales and if you sell used (older than 12 months) or new articles.

Comment: So how do you know if you have to pay or register? What happens if you don't fully understand it and just don't pay it by mistake when you should, or pay when you shouldn't? I really don't want to pay some guy here to tell me this because I'm even selling stuff on ebay because I am low on cash, so that would be extremely counter-productive.